# jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

i used mathjax.js with Zend 2 in my project.
actually i want to display preview of already submitted question & stored in

```
<mathJx>`\vec{F} = \frac{d \vec{p}}{dt} = m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} = m \vec{a}`</mathJx>
```

And display shown in popup, it shows preview correctly only for first time (after reload the page) but after that it gives the error in console and not shown preview instead string as i stored.

```
**Error in console:**
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:85:20)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Qc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at b (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Please help! thanks in advance.

Comment: You likely load the JS in incorrect order. We cannot see that from your question

Comment: ok! mentioned your suggestion, checking for them.

Comment: Code i have used on page related to mathjax: **<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    showProcessingMessages: false,
    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->basePath('js/plugins/mathjax/mathjax-preview.js'); ?>"></script>**

Comment: but it shows preview only for first time and not after that. i don't have any idea

Comment: **here is the order of JS in page: **`/js/jquery.min.js",
/js/bootstrap.min.js",
/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js",
/plugins/jquery_ui/interactions.min.js",
/js/plugins/jquery_ui/touch.min.js",
/js/app.js",
/js/ekko-lightbox-disable-backdrop.js",
/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js",
/js/plugins/forms/selects/bootstrap_multiselect.js",
/js/common.js",
/js/plugins/forms/selects/bootstrap_select.min.js",
/js/plugins/forms/selects/form_bootstrap_select.js",
/js/ekko-lightbox.js",
/js/quiz.js",
/js/scrolling.js",
/js/hawwaz.pagin.js"`

Comment: and then in bottom of page:                 `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    showProcessingMessages: false,
    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assessment-development/saif/public/js/plugins/mathjax/mathjax-preview.js"></script>`